# Counting and manipulating occurrences in text file (Perl)

Tags: arrays, perl, list, hash

I have a tab separated text file that is like

```
1J  L  0.5
1J  P  0.4
1J  K  0.2
1J  L  0.3
1B  K  0.7
1B  L  0.2
1B  P  0.3
1B  L  0.6
1B  L  0.3
```

And I want to manipulate it in order to get the following information:

For each element in the 1st column, count how many repeated elements in the second column there are, and do the average of all numbers in the third column for each element of the second column. The desired output can be another tab separated text file, where "Average" is the average number for that element in the 2nd column:

```
1st  K#  Average  L#  Average  P# Average 
1J  1  0.2  2  0.4  1  0.4
1B  1  0.7  3  0.38  1  0.3
```

How should I proceed? I thought about doing a Hash of Arrays with key = 1st column, but I don't think this would be too advantageous.

I also thought about creating multiple arrays named `@L`, `@P`, `@K` to count the occurrences of each of these elements, for each element of the 1st column; and other arrays `@Ln`, `@Pn`, `@Kn` that would get all numbers for each of these. In the end, the sum of each number divided by `scalar @L` would give me the average number.

**But my main problem in these is: how can I do all of this processing for each element of the 1st column?**

Edit: another possibility (that I am trying right now) is to create an array of all unique elements of the first column. Then, `grep`ing each one and do the processing. But there may be easier ways?

Edit2: it may happen that some elements of the second column do not exist for some elements in the first column - problem: division by 0. E.g.:

```
1J  L  0.5
1J  P  0.4
1J  K  0.2
1J  L  0.3
1B  K  0.7
1B  L  0.2
1B  L  0.3  <- note that this is not P as in the example above.  
1B  L  0.6
1B  L  0.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
my $result;
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @data = split;
    $result->{$data[0]}{$data[1]}{sum} += $data[2];
    $result->{$data[0]}{$data[1]}{nbr}++;
}
say "1st\tK#\tavg\tL#\tavg\tP#\tavg";
foreach my $k(keys %$result) {
    print "$k\t";
    for my $c (qw(K L P)) {
        if (exists($result->{$k}{$c}{nbr}) && $result->{$k}{$c}{nbr} != 0) {
            printf("%d\t%.2f\t",$result->{$k}{$c}{nbr},$result->{$k}{$c}{sum}/$result->{$k}{$c}{nbr});
        } else {
            printf("%d\t%.2f\t",0,0);
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
1J  L  0.5
1J  P  0.4
1J  K  0.2
1J  L  0.3
1B  K  0.7
1B  L  0.2
1B  P  0.3
1B  L  0.6
1B  L  0.3
```

**output:**

```
1st K#  avg   L#  avg   P#  avg
1B  1   0.70  3   0.37  1   0.30    
1J  1   0.20  2   0.40  1   0.40
```

Comment: What would you do if 1B didn't have `P` for instance, but 1J did?

Comment: I wrote at the end of your answer my edit for how it should be done, if my edit2 verifies. If you do not agree with it, feel free to delete it completely! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Untested code:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ($x, $y, $z) = split /\t/;
    push @{$f{$x}{$y}}, $z;   # E.g. $f{'1J'}{'L'}[1] will be 0.3
}

@cols = qw/L P K/;
foreach $x (sort keys %f) {
    print "$x\t";
    foreach $y (@cols) {
        $t = $n = 0;
        foreach $z (@{$f{$x}{$y}}) {
            $t += $z;
            ++$n;
        }
        $avg = $n ? $t / $n : 'N/A';
        print "$n\t$avg\t";
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: What happens if one of the elements of the 2nd column doesn't appear in one of the first column? (please see edit2)

Comment: @Sosi: If you look at the code, this case is handled by printing 'N/A'.

Comment: +1 for the overall easiest to understand script. Changing the second last print statement to ```printf("%d %.3f \t",$n,$avg);``` fixes the rounding/formatting for me. Cheers.

Comment: indeed, when I was using `printf("%d %.2f \t",$n,$avg);` I had some errors, but not with `%.3f`

Answer (score 1):

For each of the count and sum I would use a Hash of Hashes where the first column is the key to the outer hash and the second column is the key to the inner hash. So something like:

```
my (%count, %sum);
while(<>) {
    my @F = split / /, $_;

    $count{$F[0]}->{$F[1]}++;
    $sum{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} += $F[2];
}

for my $key (keys %count) {
    print $key;
    for my $subkey ("K", "L", "P") {
        my $average = defined($count{$key}->{$subkey}) ? $sum{$key}->{$subkey} / $count{$key}->{$subkey} : 0;
        ...; # and print the result
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I did this  - really - but here is a "one-liner" (ahem) that I will try to translate into a real script and explain - as an exercise for myself  **:-)** I hope this admittedly artificial example of a one line solution adds something to the more clearly written and scripted examples submitted by the others.

```
perl -anE '$seen{$F[0]}->{$F[1]}++; $sum{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} += $F[2];}{ 
for(keys %seen){say " $_:"; for $F1(sort keys $seen{$_}) { 
say "$F1","s: $seen{$_}->{$F1} avg:",$sum{$_}->{$F1}/$seen{$_}->{$F1}}}' data.txt
```

See [perlrun(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for a more detailed explanation of **Perl's** switches. Essentially, `perl -anE` starts **Perl** in "autosplit" mode (`-a`) and creates a `while <>` loop to read input (`-n`) for the code that is executed between the `' '` quotes. The `-E` turns on all the newest bells and whistles for execution (normally one uses `-e`). Here's my attempt at explaining what it does.

First, in the `while` loop this (sort of) "oneliner":

- autosplits input into an array (`@F` ... awkish for "fields" I guess) using a space as the delimitter.
- uses the [`%seen{}`](http://www.perl.com/pub/2006/11/02/all-about-hashes.html) trick to count occurrences of matching lines in part of the array. Here it increments the value of the `%seen` hash key created from column one (`$F[0]`) of `@F` each time it sees a line in column two (`$F[1]`) of `@F` that repeats
- uses a hash `%sum` or `%total` to add the values in column three (`$F[2]`) using the `=+` operator. See [this perlmonks node](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=851635) for another example.

Then it breaks out of the `while <>` loop created with `-n` by using a "[butterfly](http://grokbase.com/p/perl/perl5-porters/125xm0m64h/perl-secret-operators-manual-page)" `}{` that acts like an `END` block allowing a nested `for` loop to spit everything out. I use `$F1` as the subkey  for the inner `for` loop to remind myself that I'm getting it from the second column of the autosplit array `@F`.

Output (we need `printf` to get nicer numerical results);

```
 1B:
Ks: 1 avg:0.7
Ls: 3 avg:0.366666666666667
Ps: 1 avg:0.3
 1J:
Ks: 1 avg:0.2
Ls: 2 avg:0.4
Ps: 1 avg:0.4
```

This makes the numbers look nicer (using `printf` to format)

```
perl -anE '$seen{$F[0]}->{$F[1]}++; $sum{$F[0]}->{$F[1]} += $F[2];}{ 
for(keys %seen){say " $_:"; for $F1(sort keys $seen{$_}) {  
printf("%ss %d avg: %.2f\n", $F1, $seen{$_}->{$F1}, $sum{$_}->{$F1}/$seen{$_}->{$F1})}}' data.txt
```

Script version. It increments values of repeated keys drawn from column two (`$field[1]`) of the data; in a second hash it sums the key values drawn from column three (`$field[2]`). I wanted to  impress you with a more functional style or the exact right CPAN module for the job but had to `$work`.  Cheers and be sure to ask more **Perl** questions!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen ;
my %sum ;

while(<DATA>){
   my @fields = split ;
   $seen{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]}++ ;     
   $sum{$fields[0]}{$fields[1]} += $fields[2];  
}

for(keys %seen) {
    print "  $_:\n";
    for my $f(sort keys $seen{$_}) {
    printf("%ss %d avg: %.2f\n", 
       $f, $seen{$_}->{$f}, $sum{$_}->{$f}/$seen{$_}->{$f} );
  }
}

__DATA__
1J L 0.5
1J P 0.4
1J K 0.2
1J L 0.3
1B K 0.7
1B L 0.2
1B L 0.3
1B L 0.6
1B L 0.3
```

Comment: What happens if one of the elements of the 2nd column doesn't appear in one of the first column? (please see edit2)

Comment: With a "missing" item from the second column the code above seems to work correctly: the hash entry is not "seen" so instead of division by zero the sum/average values change for other elements.  You tell me :-)  I think I like the simpler approach used by j_random_hacker the best - it keeps things simple by avoiding some hash operations and using  list/arrays.