# Manipulating multiple lines with Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have a few-hundreds of lines file of the form

```
1st  2n  2p  3n  3p  4n  4p
1ABJa  2  20  8  40  3  45
1ABJb  2  40  8  80  3  45
2C3Da  4  50  5  39  2  90
2D4Da  1  10  8  90  8  65
```

(tab separated file)

From this file, I want to manipulate all lines that have a similar 4 beginning characters in the 1st column (i.e. 1ABJa and 1ABJb) and do:

- for column 1 merge both names maintaining the common characters;
- for columns `2n, 3n, 4n...` the numbers would be summed;
- for columns `2p, 3p, 4p, ...` the numbers would be averaged.

(note that this can be specified by column position and not name).
This would then yield:

```
1st  2n  2p  3n  3p  4n  4p
1ABJab  4  30  16  60  6  45       
2C3Da  4  50  5  39  2  90
2D4Da  1  10  8  90  8  65
```

How would you solve this?

**This is probably the most complicated way to do this, but here it goes:** I am thinking about creating an array of all 4-character unique elements of the 1st column. Then, for that array, running a loop that finds all instances matching those 4 characters. If there are more than 1 instance, identify them, push the columns, and manipulate them. Here's the point that I got until now:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my $dir='My\\Path\\To\\Directory';
open my $in,"<", "$dir\\my file.txt" or die;
my @uniqarray; my @lines;

#collects unique elements in 1st column and changes them to 4-character words
while (my $line = <$in>) {
    chomp $line;
    @lines= split '\t', $line;
    if (!grep /$lines[0]/, @uniqarray ){
        $lines[0] =~ s/^(.{4}).*/$1/;
        push @uniqarray,$lines[0];
    }
}

my @l;
#for @uniqarray, find all rows in the input that match them. if more than 1 row is found, manipulate the columns
while (my $something=<$in>) {
    chomp $something;
    @l= split '\t', $something;
    if ( map $something =~ m/$_/,@uniqarray){
        **[DO STUFF]**
    }
}

print join "\n", uniq(@uniqarray);

close $in;
```

Comment: In your example output, why is the first row `1ABJab`? You haven't specified a rule, so it seems like it could just as easily be `1ABJa`.

Comment: I gave it the name `1ABJab` because it contains data from both `1ABJa` and `1ABJb`, and I want to distinguish it from the other rows. I will add the rule for this. Thanks!

Comment: The only hard part is putting togeter the end result, since the `yeild's` looks like after the fact, the results are merged with the lines that aren't analyzed.

Comment: Nevermind, I read that too fast...I was thinking you used the name of just one of the rows (e.g. `1ABJb`), not a combination.

Comment: `'D:\'` is incorrect code, the backslash will escape your closing quote. Which is quite visible in the Markdown formatting above.

Comment: @TLP - I hided my path, that is not the real thing. Edited

Comment: @sln: sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. The results are: merged lines (`1ABJab` in my example) and original lines (`2C3Da` and `2D4Da` in my example)

Comment: how big is the big file?  is it thousands of lines or millions or billions?

Comment: @Sosi You can use slashes instead of backslash. `D:/foo/bar`.

Comment: @Vorsprung not so many lines actually, so performance is not a big problem! Just a few hundreds of lines

Comment: @sosi you probably want to store the keys in a hash then

Comment: Your going to have to store all the average columns before you can do `something` with it. This requires a third loop to inject the new line, and remove the old lines.

Comment: Are similar lines always consecutives?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte they can be reordered to be, no problem in that

Comment: Reordered? Problem solved.

Comment: @sln could you give me some more input on how to solve it? I'm kind of new in Perl..

Comment: If they are in a pack (ie. reordered), then a single loop should be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do what you need. It keeps a set of data in a hash for each distinct four-character prefix: a count of the number of records with the same prefix under key `n`, an array that holds the column totals for that prefix under key `totals`, and a hash with all the suffixes seen for that prefix under key `suffixes`.

Prefixes are added to the array `@prefixes` the first time they are seen, so that the output can be presented in the same order as the input.

It is simply a matter of accumulating the data and then dumping it in the required format, after dividing all the even-numbers columns of the `totals` array by `n`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;

print scalar <$fh>; # Copy header

my %data;
my @prefixes;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  my ($prefix, $suffix) = shift(@fields) =~ /(.{4})(.*)/;
  push @prefixes, $prefix unless $data{$prefix};
  ++$data{$prefix}{n};
  ++$data{$prefix}{suffixes}{$suffix};
  $data{$prefix}{totals}[$_] += $fields[$_] for 0 .. $#fields;
}

for my $prefix (@prefixes) {
  my $val      = $data{$prefix};
  my $totals   = $val->{totals};
  for (my $i = 1; $i < @$totals; $i += 2) {
    $totals->[$i] /= $val->{n};
  }
  my $suffixes = join '', sort keys %{ $val->{suffixes} };
  print join("\t", "$prefix$suffixes", @$totals), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
1st     2n  2p  3n  3p  4n  4p
1ABJab  4   30  16  60  6   45
2C3Da   4   50  5   39  2   90
2D4Da   1   10  8   90  8   65
```

Comment: wow this is really elegant! I need to have a good look at those array refs that you used tomorrow! thanks

Comment: ok, now I got it! thanks for the help! It works perfectly even in my real case

Comment: `++$data{$prefix}{n}` could also be `$data{$prefix}{n}++`, or when creating that hash value do you need it to be incremented before? I know that `->` has operator precedence over `++` so both ways are equivalent right?

Comment: @Sosi: Yes, the two are equivalent. The only reason people use the postfixed `$x++` by default when it doesn't matter is because of the name of the language C++. It's useful to reverse that habit as there are some languages that do the extra work to preserve the pre-increment value even when it isn't used.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
my $result;
my $head = <DATA>;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @l = split/\s+/;
    my ($k1,$k2) = ($l[0] =~ /^(....)(.*)$/);
    $result->{$k1}{more} .= $k2 // '';
    $result->{$k1}{nbr}++;

    ;
    $result->{$k1}{n}{2} += $l[1];
    $result->{$k1}{n}{3} += $l[3];
    $result->{$k1}{n}{4} += $l[5];
    $result->{$k1}{p}{2} += $l[2];
    $result->{$k1}{p}{3} += $l[4];
    $result->{$k1}{p}{4} += $l[6];
}

print $head;
foreach my $k (keys %$result) {
    print $k,$result->{$k}{more},"\t";
    for my $c (2,3,4) {
        printf("%d\t",$result->{$k}{n}{$c});
        if (exists($result->{$k}{nbr}) && $result->{$k}{nbr} != 0) {
            printf("%d\t",$result->{$k}{p}{$c}/$result->{$k}{nbr});
        } else {
            printf("%d\t",0);
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
1st     2n  2p  3n  3p  4n  4p
2D4Da   1   10  8   90  8   65  
1ABJab  4   30  16  60  6   45  
2C3Da   4   50  5   39  2   90
```

Comment: eheh actually it reminds me of your answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764615/counting-and-manipulating-occurrences-in-text-file-perl) thread! I still need to get the hang of these hashes' references.
Just a couple of questions (and please redirect me to the documentation if it is simpler, I am trying to learn): 1. `$result->{$k1}{n}{2}` means `$result->{$k1}`? 2.What can you do with the names you gave (i.e. `n` or `2`)?

Comment: @Sosi: I don't follow. Why should you think that `$result->{$k1}{n}{2}` is the same as `$result->{$k1}`? And the values used as hash keys, `$k1`, `n` and `2` are simple strings. A bareword like `n` is implicitly quoted when is appears as a hash key. You can do anything with them that you can do with strings.

Comment: @M42: The OP's *"for columns 2n, 3n, 4n... the numbers would be summed"* implies to me that there a probably more than the six columns of data shown in the example

Comment: @Borodin: Yes, I guess you're right, but I leave the rest as an exercice. He just needs to reorganize with some loops.

Comment: @Borodin indeed, I'm using about 40 columns. But I'll see if I can expand from what M42 did!

Comment: @M42: I am just not very used to all that notation in hashes

Comment: @M42 Ok, I got it now! I'm sorry for my first two questions in the comments, I can see now how they do not make sense