# perl better method for counting each array element occurance

Tags: perl, machine-learning, svm

I have 2 arrays, one is the root array, which contains huge mount of elements. Another is the tested array, all of which elements is a subset of root array. I want to  construct a new array, with size equal to root arrays, and its element value at a specific position represents the count of that element in the tested array.

Below codes works well when 2 array size is small. But the practical problem I meet is that, the root arrays has about 15000 elements, and there are about 14000 tested  arrays.
I wonder to have better algorithm. Do you guys have some suggestions?

```
my @root=qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10);
my @aa=qw(1 1 2 3);
my @count;

foreach my $eleroot(@root){
my $mathnum=0;
my ($i) = grep { $root[$_] ~~ $eleroot } 0 .. $#root;
foreach my $eleaa(@aa){
 if ($eleroot==$eleaa){
  $mathnum++;
   }
 }
 $count[$i]=$mathnum;

}
print @count;
```

Comment: You won't get favourable answers if you don't even attempt to write a solution yourself.

Comment: Those values aren't frequencies: they're simple counts.

Comment: Go ahead and try a solution, then we'll be happy to offer suggestions to improve your code. A solution would probably use a hash of hash to hold the data with the 'id' as the key to the outer hash and the column numbers seen as the keys to the inner hash. Like `$seen{$id}{$col}++`. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764615/counting-and-manipulating-occurrences-in-text-file-perl/22765327#22765327)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly suggestions. I have tried for about 8 hours and get it. But it is not good when array amount and size increase. Hope to discuss with you

Comment: From the size of the root (15,000) array and the number of arrays to test (14,000), it seems not likely that you would want to print them all out to a file. I would instead use a database, (SQLite good choice), and enter the counts for each test array result as a row with the root as a header. But it is difficult to tell what you want to do with the results at this point. I need more information to offer a solution.

Comment: Also, your new sample data doesn't match what you originally posted and makes it difficult to tell what results in what format you  want.

Comment: Please don't use the broken, experimental `~~` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better algorithm would be to use a hash to keep counts. For your sample arrays, it would look like this. (And will run considerably faster than your solution).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @root=qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10);
my @aa=qw(1 1 2 3);

print join("\t", @root), "\n";

my %seen;
for my $data (@aa) {
    $seen{$data}++; 
}

print join("\t", map {$_ // '0'} @seen{@root}), "\n";
```

Output is:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       10
2       1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

`@seen{@root}` is a hash slice keyed by the `@root` array. If no item was found for any of the `@root` elements, the map supplies a zero.

The `map {$_ // '0'}` portion is saying pass to `join` a count if `$_` has a count otherwise pass a zero.

Comment: Nice! For simple counting, I also like to compress that `for` loop into one line: `$seen{$_}++ for @aa`